# Android Keyboard Character Validation

Tags: android, validation, keyboard, textwatcher

I want an **EditText** on an Android application to restrict which characters a user is allowed to type into it.

For example, maybe I don't want my users to be able to type the letter 'X' on my text box. If they tap the X key on the soft keyboard, the input should simply be ignored.

I get the impression I could use the **TextWatcher** to regulate which characters can be typed into a text box, but I'm not quite sure the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in xml `EditText`

```
android:digits="abcdef-jklmn"
```

don't add the character you dont wanna user to imput.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            s = removeChars(s);

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

 public static String removeChars(String input) {

    String charactersToDelete = "áàäéèëíìïóòöúùuñÁÀÄÉÈËÍÌÏÓÒÖÚÙÜÑçÇQWERTYUIOPÑLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM";

    String output = input;
    for (int i=0; i<original.length(); i++) {
        output.replaceAll(charactersToDelete.charAt(i)+"", "");
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one may it help..

```
 editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode)
 {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
            //handle code for pressing 0
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

});